# Oracle connection works on one server but not another

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, dll

I have an ASP.NET (4.0) application developed in Visual Studio 2012 (C#) with an Oracle (4.121.1.0) connection.  A connection string is used so we are not looking at TNS.

The application runs without issue in debug on my development server (Windows 2008 R2 SP1), where I have the Oracle DataAccess components.

I can publish the project to my Production server (Windows 2008 R2), running IIS, but had to place the following dlls into the bin folder of the application.

- oci.dll
- Oracle.DataAccess.dll  (published with application)
- orannzsbb12.dll
- oraocci12.dll
- oraociei12.dll
- oraons.dll
- OraOps12.dll

I created an application pool for this app using 4.0 integrated and set "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to true.

The oracle connection runs successfully on this environment.

But now, when I publish the exact same code to my Test server (Windows 2008 R2 SP1), and copy the same dlls to the bin folder and set up my application pool the same as my production environment, I get:

### *The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client*

This is the line of code that errors out on the TEST server:

```
oracleConnection = new OracleConnection();
```

I've verified that everything is the same between both PROD and TEST servers, but the TEST server gives me this error WITHOUT EXCEPTION and the PROD server runs PERFECTLY.

Neither PROD nor TEST servers have the Oracle DataAccess components installed.

Any suggestions on what to check?

Thanks.

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of time and hassle by using [Oracle's managed driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/). It doesn't have any external dependencies and isn't architecture specific.

Comment: It sounds to me you have Oracle installed in the GAC on the machine with the error and it is not the same version as you have in your BIN. Since Oracle uses the TNSNames to connect, you must have a different version installed on that server.  There should be no need to move those DLL in the BIN. I use the same version and only use GAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Mason's suggestion, I converted to the Oracle Managed Data Access driver which resolved the problem.  So much simpler and resolved the issue.